# Program counting words c

Tags: c, counting

I got a almost good working program to count words from standard input.
The word what has to be count is a program argument.

The problem is that I use a white space to see a word but I also must count within th word itself.
Example: if my input is aa aaaa #EOF,  and I want to count aa the result should be 4. My code result 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int word_cnt(const char *s, char *argv[])
{
    int cnt = 0;

    while(*s != '\0')
    {
        while(isspace(*s))
        ++s;
        if(*s != '\0')
        {
            if(strncmp(s, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
            ++cnt;

            while(!isspace(*s) && *s != '\0')
            ++s;
        }
     }

    return cnt;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[1026] = {'\0'};
    char *p="#EOF\n";
    int tellen = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Kan het programma niet uitvoeren, er is geen programma argument gevonden\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while((strcmp(buf, p) !=0))
    {
        fgets (buf, 1025, stdin);
        tellen += word_cnt(buf, argv);
    }

    printf("%d", tellen);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wha? You have two words: `aa` and `aaaa`

Comment: `if my input is aa aaaa #EOF, and I want to count aa the result should be 4` Why should your result be 4?

Comment: because of the word aaaa actually has 3 times aa,  first one is **aa** aa, second a**aa**a, and the thrird, aa**aa**.

Comment: It's almost like he's looking for a non-greedy regex. Because in the grouping of "aa aaaa" there are four possible sets for the subset aa.

Comment: Now that's the strangest concept of _word_ I've seen.

Comment: Your code defines anything but a space as a word character. We don't usually think of comma or quote characters as word characters. But I don't think it matters to your question.

Comment: @jweyrich He needs to count all occurrence of the substring in the file, not word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int word_cnt(const char *s, char *argv[])
{
    int cnt = 0;
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    while(*s)
    {
            if(strncmp(s, argv[1], len) == 0)
              ++cnt;

            ++s;
     }

    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually really easy and understandable. I was actually experminenting with the size of checking words.

Answer (score 3):

Where you have this:

```
if(strncmp(s, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
    ++cnt;

while(!isspace(*s) && *s != '\0')
    ++s;
```

Try this:

```
/* if it matches, count and skip over it */
while (strncmp(s, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0) {
    ++cnt;
    s += strlen(argv[1]);
}

/* if it no longer matches, skip only one character */
++s;
```

Comment: Just read the comments above. To make it give you 4 for aa aaaa while looking for aa, only add 1 if it matches instead of adding the full length of the match. What I show will give you 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try [strncmp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncmp.html) in a loop.

```
/* UNTESTED */
unsigned wc(const char *input, const char *word) {
    unsigned count = 0;
    while (*input) {
        if (strncmp(input, word, strlen(word)) == 0) count++;
        input++;
    }
    return count;
}
```